# Почему не срабатывает .load()?

Tags: jquery

Пишу такой код:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
 $('#out').load("form.html");
 alert('1');
});
```

form.html лежит в той же папке. Но загрузка не выполняется, хотя и ошибок не выдает.
  Из-за чего может быть такое?

Comment: а alert() срабатывает ?

Comment: да, срабатывает, ошибок в коде нет. И, кажется, load не работает только на локальной машине.

Comment: Да, load на локальной машине не работает.

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov а локальная машина имеется ввиду html файл ? в смысле без сервера ? load() использует XMLHttpRequest , в данном случае ключевое слово http, нет http - нет запроса.